# Overall sum rating with best outcome

Tags: python, random, grouping, repeat

I have a system that makes random groups of 4, then rates them:

```
import numpy
import math
import random
for i in range(1):
  # everything is in, see the indentation
  members=4
  n_groups =4
  participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
  #print participants 
  random.shuffle(participants)

  with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
      for i in range(n_groups):
          group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
          for participant in group:
              tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
          tf.write('\n')

  with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
      g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
      print(g)




  my_groups =g

  def get_rating(group):
      return len(set(group))

  for each_grp in my_groups:  
      print((get_rating(each_grp)))
```

This gives the output:

```
[[1, 3, 2, 1], [4, 4, 3, 3], [2, 2, 1, 3], [1, 4, 4, 2]]
3
2
3
3
```

Is there a way I can sum the 4 ratings to get an overall score? Like in this case (3+2+3+3)=11, also if I change:
    for i in range(1):
Which changes the amount of loops it does so:
    for i in range(5):
Would run the code 5 times with different outcomes, is there a code to find the best overall score out of the 5 trials?

Basically Is there anything I can use to sum up the 4 ratings, then if repeated can it pick the best overall score out off all the repeats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a running total:

```
total = 0
for each_grp in my_groups:
    c = get_rating(each_grp)
    total += c
    print(c)
```

You can take the original `list` and use a generator to `sum` up the `len` of the `set`:

```
>>> sum(get_rating(each_grp) for each_group in my_groups)
11
```

Comment: This works really well! Is there any way, when i do more repeats can it find the sum of the ratings that is the lowest?